# Fourier transformation with mathdotnet in F#

Tags: f#, f#-data, math.net, mathnet-numerics

I am trying to use the Math.NET numerics implementation of the FFT algorithm, but I must be doing something wrong because the output is always unit

The following is the the setup:

```
open MathNet.Numerics
open MathNet.Numerics.Statistics
open MathNet.Numerics.IntegralTransforms
let rnd = new Random()
let rnddata = Array.init 100 (fun u -> rnd.NextDouble())
let x = rnddata |> Array.Parallel.map (fun d -> MathNet.Numerics.complex.Create(d, 0.0) )
```

then when I run this:

```
let tt = MathNet.Numerics.IntegralTransforms.Fourier.BluesteinForward(x, FourierOptions.Default)
```

I receive an empty output below?

```
val tt : unit = ()
```

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the `Fourier.BluesteinForward` method stores the results in the input array (by overwriting whatever was there originally).

If you do not need the input after running the transform, you can just use `x` and read the results (this saves some memory copying, which is why Math.NET does that by default). Otherwise, you can clone the array and wrap it in a more functional style code like this:

```
let bluesteinForward input = 
  let output = Array.copy input
  MathNet.Numerics.IntegralTransforms.Fourier.BluesteinForward
    (output, FourierOptions.Default)
  output
```

Comment: Wouldn't `Array.copy` be more idiomatic than `Array.map id`? Is there a hidden drawback I'm missing?

Comment: @ildjarn You're absolutely right, `Array.copy` is better! I just didn't have VS around and thought it should be "clone" but could not find it!